# How to change url (Numbers) to alphabet words?

Tags: php, html, function

This might be a very basic question.

I have bought space from a web supplier. They have given me a url which is numbers like `http://107.170.253.5/`. I wondered how can I change it to an alphabet link such as `myfirstwebsite.com.au`.

Appreciate any suggestion...

Comment: you should buy a domain, and set the DNS record to point to that ip

Comment: @Nanne   I thought I bought a domain! So what they call the ip I have? Do you the difference?

Comment: @Bernard, You can even map that yourself in your hosting panel.

Comment: find your DNS settings. look for words like nameserver. then call your host and have them help you :)

Comment: I think I need to buy domain now. First I paid $5 for space and now time for domain!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of [`gethostbyaddr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) in PHP:

```
//Get the Internet host name corresponding to a given IP address
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr('107.170.253.5');
echo $hostname; //<---- To print the hostname
```

Edit:

> This is not working. it is giving me a link to my wireless!

That actually works, you have not mapped your domain with the IP address. See the below example and it works perfectly:

```
<?php
echo $ip = gethostbyname('www.stackoverflow.com'); //"prints" 198.252.206.140
echo gethostbyaddr($ip); //"prints" stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: this is assuming there is a hostname connected to that ip?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't *have* a host name associated with his IP address

Comment: @Gareth, You are right.  May I know the reason for the downvote (unknown guy) ?

Comment: I was the downvote. You've perfectly described how `gethostbyname` works, but that's nothing to do with what Bernard was asking. His problem is related to his domain's DNS settings (or lack of them)